# How to evaluate these expressions?

Tags: c, boolean-logic

int a = 17 (=10001)

int b=5 (101)

```
a&b      1         bitwise AND
a|b     21         bitwise OR
a^b     20         XOR (16+4) “just one”
a&&b     1         logical AND
a||b     1         logical OR
-b      -5         minus b
~b       -6         ?
~(~a)      17        ?
!b       0         logical “NOT B”
!(!a))   1         logical “NOT NOT A”
a=b      0         “a==b?”
a=’A’   65         ?
a|’@’   64         ?
```

Can you please help me explain the parts where the ? is.

Comment: value of `a = b` is 5; value of `a == b` is 0

Comment: In C, `a=b` and `a='A'` are not just assignments, they are `assignment expressions` and as such have values (just like `a+b`), those are the values that get assigned to the variable (`b` and `'A'`, respectively), IOW, the new (post-assignment) values of the variable.

Comment: This looks like homework and should be tagged as such. If it isn't, ignore this comment. :)

Comment: @leemes It says the homework tag should not be used. It is homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~b       -6         ?
```

The "~"  flips all the bits, and negative numbers are represented using something called [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2s_complement). The -6 is just what happens when you flip all the bits of "5": you get a different bitpattern, which is the same bits as "-6" in 2s complement.

```
~(~a)      17        ?
```

Similar. Flip all the bits, then flip all the bits again, and what do you get? The same as before.

```
a=’A’   65         ?
```

Internally, characters are represented by numbers, just like everything else in a computer. Virtually all these number<->character tables in use today are based on [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), and 'A' just happens to have the number 65 in the ASCII table.

```
a|’@’   64         ?
```

That doesn't make sense. '@' is 64 (ASCII, again), which is hex 0x40. 0x40 | 17 should be 81.

Comment: "Internally, characters are represented by numbers, just like everything else in a computer." A little bit better would be: "Internally, characters are represented by some bits, just like everything else in a computer, like numbers." Because numbers are already an *interpretation* of some bits. (Otherwise we wouldn't need something like the two's complement, since -1 is a number! But it needs to be stored using some bits and thus needs a kind of interpretation and representation.)

Comment: This is the moste elaborate answer since it spec mentions 2s complement that I was unsure of was getting used.

Answer (score 2):

`-` is unary negative. It just takes the negative of the value, assuming no overflow. And negative 5 is obviously `-5'.

`~` is bitwise complement. I'd recommend you lookup how it works. In two's complement, `~x` is equivalent to `-x - 1`. And for `~(~a)`, obviously the complement of the complement is the original number.

For the last two, you are just taking a character and treating it as a number. This just uses the ascii value of the character. The value of 'A' is 65, but I highly doubt your teacher expects you to memorize them all. You'll probably get an ascii table.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that a = 17 (10001 binary) and b = 5 (101 binary) we have:

```
a&b      1         bitwise AND
a|b     21         bitwise OR
a^b     20         XOR (16+4) “just one”
a&&b     1         logical AND
a||b     1         logical OR
-b      -5         minus b
~b       -6         bitwise NOT 
~(~a)      17        bitwise NON NOT - the same as a
!b       0         logical “NOT B”
!(!a))   1         logical “NOT NOT A”
a=b      5         assignment to a the value of b
a='A'   65         assignment to a the ASCII value of char 'A'
a|'@'   81         a OR ASCII value of char '@'
```

Comment: @pmg to your last edit... if we assume that two last rows are executed sequentially the resulting value would be 65

Comment: right, but I don't think that's the idea of the OP. After all he posted a bunch of simple expressions, not statements.

Comment: @pmg then why did you change 64 with 81?

Comment: I changed 69 (result of `5 | 64`) to 81 (result of `17 | 64`). The original post had 64, which I had changed previously to 69 (thinking `a` had the value 5).

Answer (score 1):

The `~` operator is bitwise NOT, which means all bits of the `int` are inverted. What effect that will have on the number depends on the type and implementation.

The `|` operator is a bitwise OR. In C, it is perfectly valid to OR an `int` with a `char`, as you do in a|'A'. The value of the `char` is then the ASCII number.

The `=` operator is assignment. The result of an assignment is whatever has been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
~b - binary NOT b
~(~a) - binary NOT ( NOT a )
a='@' - assign the int value of '@' to a
a|'A' - bitwise OR with the int value of 'A'
```

Comment: `'@'` is an int. There is no conversion from/to `char`

Comment: @pmg Are you sure? I thought `'_'` (where `_` is an arbitrary character) is of type char, NOT int.

Comment: In C, `'_'` is of type `int` (I believe it's different in C++). See 6.4.4.4/10 in the [C2011 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

- `=` : Assignment operator.
- `~` : Bitwise `NOT` operator (logical negation on each bit).
- `|` : Bitwise `OR` operator (logical inclusive `OR` on each bit).